# SQL Server T-SQL query slow for the first run , then run fast

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a very simple stored procedure; it run slowly for the first time, then runs fast if same input parameters.

It returns 2 tables, the first table is returned fast, but the second table, it became slow as I join it with table 1 result to get the correct data

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PR_ReadMdgObj]
      (@objId int,
       @dtFrom datetime = NULL,
       @dtTo datetime = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    DECLARE @engine_SensorSource_id INT

    SELECT @engine_SensorSource_id = SensorSourceid 
    FROM dbo.SensorSource 
    WHERE sourcenameid = 1 
      AND objectid = @objId  

    CREATE TABLE #10msgtable 
    (
        rownum int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        MessageId bigint NOT NULL,
        ObjectId int NOT NULL,
        VectorAngle int NOT NULL,
        VectorSpeed int NOT NULL,
        Altitude int NOT NULL,
        GpsTime datetime NOT NULL,
        VisibleSatelites int NULL,
        X float, Y float,
        engine int,
        st int
    );

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_returnTable10_GpsTime 
    ON #10msgtable (GpsTime);

    INSERT INTO #10msgtable 
        SELECT 
            [Message].messageid, [Message].objectid, 
            [Message].vectorangle, [Message].vectorspeed, 
            [Message].altitude, [Message].gpstime, 
            [Message].visiblesatelites, 
            [Message].x, [Message].y, 
            0 Engine, 0 as t
        FROM   
            dbo.[Message] WITH (nolock) 
        WHERE  
            [Message].ObjectId = @objId
            AND [Message].GpsTime BETWEEN @dtFrom AND @dtTo 
            --  AND m.Valid = 1 
            -- AND m.VectorSpeed < 250 

    DELETE FROM #10msgtable 
    WHERE VectorSpeed = 250;

    SELECT * 
    FROM #10msgtable 
    ORDER BY GpsTime ASC

    --- select 2
    SELECT 
        MessageSensors.MessageId,
        SensorSource.SourceNameId,
        MessageSensors.Value 
    FROM 
        dbo.MessageSensors 
    INNER JOIN
        #10msgtable WITH (nolock) ON MessageSensors.MessageId= #10msgtable.MessageId
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.SensorSource WITH (nolock) ON SensorSource.SensorSourceId = MessageSensors.SensorSourceId
    --where MessageSensors.MessageId in (select MessageId from #10msgtable)

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
END
```

Here is my actual execution plan:

https://gist.github.com/aymanstar/3ed882c6330ee6252751ce9dd2f5beac

Comment: The reason it runs faster is because the queries and execution plans are cached. This means if the parameters don't change the query will be faster the second time you run it

Comment: i know ,that , but how to optimize the query  and why it slow ? its just normal read without any complex calculations

Comment: What does "first run" mean? Like after you've restarted SQL Server? First run will be slow typically because all of the data has to be read from disk into memory. Once the data is cached, it will be faster on subsequent runs, unless something forces the data out of memory again in the meantime. It is unlikely to cause a noticeable difference if the execution plans are cached or not; while not impossible, compilation in and of itself is unlikely to cause a significant, noticeable delay (unless SQL Server generates a much less efficient plan this time).

Comment: i mean first execute  take 1 m 30 second , second only 5 seconds and so on

Comment: If you *already* set `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`, then you most definitely don't need those `WITH (NOLOCK)` hints everywhere - you're **already** reading potentially dirty and uncommitted data anyway.....

Comment: nice catch marc_s , but even without - speed is the same ?

Comment: NOLOCK / READ UNCOMMITTED does not make your query run faster, except in some scenarios where the query is slow due to blocking (in which case RCSI is almost always a better solution). And there are a lot of costs involved with just blindly slapping NOLOCK / READ UNCOMMITTED everywhere, assuming it will speed up all your queries. See http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for sharing this link , my table have a too much transactions thats why it wait until insert complete , i used to bypass this by no lock , i will try RCSI

Answer (score 0):

There are few unnecessary steps you've added. And the first run will be always slow(as you've already knew). 
In your script

1. There are no need to add `with(nolock)` the reason is explaned by @marc_s
2. Unnecessary variable declaration(@engine_SensorSource_id).
3. No need to perform `delete` if you filter out the data in first attempt.

So modified script should be like:-

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PR_ReadMdgObj] (
    @objId INT
    ,@dtFrom DATETIME = NULL
    ,@dtTo DATETIME = NULL
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    --DECLARE @engine_SensorSource_id INT

    --SELECT @engine_SensorSource_id = SensorSourceid
    --FROM dbo.SensorSource
    --WHERE sourcenameid = 1
    --  AND objectid = @objId

    CREATE TABLE #10msgtable (
        rownum INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
        ,MessageId BIGINT NOT NULL
        ,ObjectId INT NOT NULL
        ,VectorAngle INT NOT NULL
        ,VectorSpeed INT NOT NULL
        ,Altitude INT NOT NULL
        ,GpsTime DATETIME NOT NULL
        ,VisibleSatelites INT NULL
        ,X FLOAT
        ,Y FLOAT
        ,engine INT
        ,st INT
        );

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_returnTable10_GpsTime ON #10msgtable (
        MessageId
        ,GpsTime
        );

    INSERT INTO #10msgtable
    SELECT [Message].messageid
        ,[Message].objectid
        ,[Message].vectorangle
        ,[Message].vectorspeed
        ,[Message].altitude
        ,[Message].gpstime
        ,[Message].visiblesatelites
        ,[Message].x
        ,[Message].y
        ,0 Engine
        ,0 AS t
    FROM dbo.[Message]
    WHERE [Message].ObjectId = @objId
        AND [Message].GpsTime BETWEEN @dtFrom
            AND @dtTo
        AND VectorSpeed <> 250

    --  AND m.Valid = 1 
    -- AND m.VectorSpeed < 250 
    --DELETE
    --FROM #10msgtable
    --WHERE VectorSpeed = 250;

    SELECT *
    FROM #10msgtable
    ORDER BY GpsTime ASC

    --- select 2
    SELECT MessageSensors.MessageId
        ,SensorSource.SourceNameId
        ,MessageSensors.Value
    FROM dbo.MessageSensors
    INNER JOIN #10msgtable ON MessageSensors.MessageId = #10msgtable.MessageId
    INNER JOIN dbo.SensorSource ON SensorSource.SensorSourceId = MessageSensors.SensorSourceId

    --where MessageSensors.MessageId in (select MessageId from #10msgtable)
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
END
```

Comment: @ engine_SensorSource_id for the next propose as i will use it later , i use delete from temp table , as this column not included in the index and the original table is large , so i filter from returned results , 
with(no lock)  , i agreed  that no needs for it , but it will not delay the read speed ?